# Weird Behavior about notifyDatasetChanged refreshment

Tags: android

## Background

Hi, I am new to Android and trying to get familiar with `ListView`. So I decide to write a simple program for user to enter quotes and display them in order. I implement a `StringAdapter` and call the `notifyDataSetChanged` every time when the user confirms.

## Question

The weird thing is that the `ListView` would sometimes update the oldest quotes and sometimes the newer one. and I don't know the problem.

[image: Picture]

Please ignore the `view data` button. In this state, I have entered four quotes:

1. Quotes: hi - Signature:William Shakespeare
2. Quotes: hello - Signature:William Shakespeare
3. Quotes: Virtue is bold and goodness never fearful. - Signature:William Shakespeare
4. Quotes: Love all, trust a few, do wrong to none. - Signature:William Shakespeare

(in reverse order, meaning in time sequence, it goes 4,3,2,1)

## Code

### main activity

```
public class storage extends AppCompatActivity {

    // the adapter
    private StringAdapter sa;
    // the edit text view 
    public EditText etString,etSignature;
    // the list view
    public ListView lv;
    // the array list to capture the quotes and signature
    private ArrayList<String[]> dataString = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    // add the string and notify
    public void addString(String[] s){
        this.dataString.add(0,s);
        ((BaseAdapter)this.lv.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_storage);

        // Link the view elements
        this.etString = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etInput);
        this.etSignature = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSignature);
        this.lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.stringList);
        Button btn_confirm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConfirm),
                btn_viewData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnViewData);

        // load the adapter
        this.sa = new StringAdapter(this,this.dataString);
        lv.setAdapter(sa);

        btn_confirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                storage s = (storage) v.getContext();

                // get the String
                String sString = s.etString.getText().toString(),
                        sSignature = s.etSignature.getText().toString();
                System.out.println("Quotes: " + sString + "\nSignature:" + sSignature);

                // verify it is not empty
                if (!sString.isEmpty()&&!sSignature.isEmpty()) {
                    // add new string and notify
                    s.addString(new String[]{s.etString.getText().toString(),
                                           s.etSignature.getText().toString()});
                    ((StringAdapter) s.lv.getAdapter()).print_stringData();

                    // prompt the result
                    Toast.makeText(s.getBaseContext(),
    "Enter Quotes from"+etSignature.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    // prompt the result
                    Toast.makeText(s.getBaseContext(),
    "Please Enter Quotes and Signatures!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

### StringAdapter

```
public class StringAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    private ArrayList<String[]> dataStrings = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    public StringAdapter(Context c,ArrayList<String[]> dataStrings){this.mContext=c;this.dataStrings=dataStrings;}

    public int getCount(){return this.dataStrings.size();}

    public Object getItem(int position){ return this.dataStrings.get(position);}

    public long getItemId(int postion){ return (long) postion;}

    public void print_stringData(){
        System.out.println("String Adapter Output:");
        for(String [] s: this.dataStrings){
            System.out.println("Quotes: "+s[0]+"\nSignature:"+s[1]);
        }
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        LinearLayout ll;
        if(convertView == null){
            // set the linear layout
            ll = new LinearLayout(this.mContext);
            ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            ll.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            // get the data and set the text inside
            String[] data = this.dataStrings.get(position);
            TextView //tvNo = new TextView(this.mContext),
                    tvString = new TextView(this.mContext),
                    tvSignature = new TextView(this.mContext);
            ll.addView(tvString);
            ll.addView(tvSignature);


            tvString.setText(data[0]);
            tvString.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            tvSignature.setText(data[1]);
            tvSignature.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tvSignature.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        }
        else{
            ll = (LinearLayout) convertView;
        }
        return ll;
    }
}
```

## Comments

Some might notice that I add the `String[]` always to the first element. Actually I have tried to add to the last. The weird behavior still exists.

## Environment

Android SDK Version: API 23 lollipop

Emulator Version: Nexus S API 23

Comment: Just for code styling/readability, simply declare a global Context variable like `Context mContext` and set it to `this` in the onCreate() method of your activity - you don't need to ask your views what Context to use. And there is no need calling this to assign (xml)Views to Views in java. Just call the variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course, you get that error. Why? Because `ListView` always re-use `convertView` in your `getView` function of `Adapter`.

Look at your `if,else`:

```
else{
    ll = (LinearLayout) convertView;
}
return ll;
```

At this block, you tell the `adapter` reuse the `convertView`, but you dont re-set the data. As a result, it will show the data of the previous row.

How to resolve it? just set the data in `else` block as you do in `if` one.

P/s: you should learn how to use `ViewHolder` in `ListView` to avoid laggy in when scrolling.